# Sorting array with date types

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

Still new to this. I encountered a problem when trying to sort an array of objects with a Date type. For example: I have 3 cars with: (Name, Date of first registration(type Date)). How do I sort this array? Should I change date to string? Thanks.

```js
function car(Make, Model, Date) {
  return Make + Model + Date;
}
var date1 = '2010';
var date2 = '2003';
var date3 = '2015';

var d1 = new Date(date1);
var d2 = new Date(date2);
var d3 = new Date(date3);

var n1 = d1.getFullYear();
var n2 = d2.getFullYear();
var n3 = d3.getFullYear();

var x = car('Mercedes', ' c220 ', n1);
var y = car(' Toyota', ' Prius ', n2);
var z = car(' Audi', ' a3 ', n3);
var polje = [x, y, z];

console.log(polje);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0 }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) and [*Sort Javascript Object Array By Date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date). I fail to see the point of converting  a year value to a Date just to read back the same value, `new Date('2010').getFullYear()` is identical to `+2010`. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Date#toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for a sortable string with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Then you could use this for sorting

```js
var array = [
        { make: 'Mercedes', model: 'c220', date : new Date('2010') },
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius', date : new Date('2003') },
        { make: 'Audi', model: 'a3', date : new Date('2015') }
    ];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.date.toISOString().localeCompare(b.date.toISOString());
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version with

- firstRegistration, desc,
- make, asc,
- model, asc

```js
var array = [
        { make: 'Mercedes', model: 'c220', firstRegistration: 2010 },
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius', firstRegistration: 2015 },
        { make: 'Audi', model: 'a3', firstRegistration: 2015 }
    ];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.firstRegistration - a.firstRegistration ||
        a.make.localeCompare(b.make) ||
        a.model.localeCompare(b.model);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! add up question: how do i make the date to show only the year? just for better looks of the output :)

Comment: you could use [`Date#getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear).

Comment: You can remove all date processing and get the same result. The *date* field should be *yearOfManufacture* and be a number, like `2010`. But hey, it "works". ;-)